# jQuery - Perform a Calculation

Tags: jquery

I have the following 3 input fields in a form:

```
<input id="a" name="a" type="text" />
<input id="b" name="b" type="text" />
<input id="c" name="c" type="text" />
```

and the following paragraph:

```
<p id="grand_total"></p>
```

I want to multiply the three text inputs together and fill in the `grand_total` with the result.

I only want the result to appear when we have filled in all three text inputs with integers between 0 and 1000.

Also if any of the text field values are changed to another valid integer then I want the `grand_total` to be re-calculated.  Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What do you have so far? Is there something in particular that isn't working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@brendan put me in the right direction, thanks. The code below works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#a, #b, #c').change(function () {
    var a = parseInt( $("#a").val(), 10 );
    var b = parseInt( $("#b").val(), 10 );
    var c = parseInt( $("#c").val(), 10 );
    a = isNaN(a) ? 0 : a;
    b = isNaN(b) ? 0 : b;
    c = isNaN(b) ? 0 : c;
    ( a > 0 && a < 1000 && b > 0 && b < 1000 && c > 0 && c < 1000 ) ? $('#grand_total').html( a * b * c ) : $('#grand_total').html(0);
  });

});
```

Comment: You don't need the `isNaN()` tests. If they _are_ `NaN`, the inputs will return false upon the comparisons. Also, you would do better to change the last line to: `$('#grand_total').text(a > 0 && a < 1000 && b > 0 && b < 1000 && c > 0 && c < 1000 ? a * b * c : "");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($("#a").val().length && $("#b").val().length && $("#c").val().length)
{
    $("#grand_total").html((parseInt($("#a").val()) + parseInt($("#b").val()) + parseInt($("#c").val())));
}
```

What this does is check whether all the inputs have values in them. If they all contain something, the inner statement parses all the values as `int`s and plugs the output into `grand_total`

If you want to parse as `float`s instead of `int`s, simply replace `parseInt()` with `parseFloat()`

Cheers,

James

Answer (score 0):

This code will make sure each value is a number, if it is not it will default to 0 for that value:

```
$("#a").change(Calc());
$("#b").change(Calc());
$("#c").change(Calc());    

function Calc() {
var vals = [];
vals.push($("#a").val());
vals.push($("#b").val());
vals.push($("#c").val());

var a = isNaN(parseInt(vals[0])) ? 0 : parseInt(vals[0]);
var b = isNaN(parseInt(vals[1])) ? 0 : parseInt(vals[1]);
var c = isNaN(vals[2]) ? 0 : parseInt(vals[3]);

if(a>-1 && a<1001 && b>-1 && b<1001 && c>-1 && c<1001)
  $("#grand_total").html(a * b * c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I ensure the numbers are integers between 0 and 1000?

Comment: If the value is not an int pareInt will return NaN and then default to 0 - added code to make sure the value is btwn 0 adn 1000.

Comment: How do I use an event listener so that the behaviour is as described in my question?  ie Only do the calculation when all three text inputs have valid integers in them.

Comment: You really should learn to optimize your selectors -- using the same selector more than once is inefficient if the DOM structure hasn't changed.  Also, you can take advantage of popular idioms like `||` to shorten your code and make it easier to read, e.g. `var a = parseInt($("#a").val, 10) || 0;` or even `var a = +$("#a").val() || 0;`.

Comment: updated to consolidate selectors and add a change event handler

Answer (score 0):

```
function calcSum(inputs) {
  var sum = 0;
  var error = false;

  inputs.each(function () {
    var value = +$(this).val() || 0;
    if (value < 0 || value > 1000) {
      error = true;
      return false; //Stops "each" loop
    }
    sum += value;
  });

  if (error) {
    ("#grand_total").text("Invalid number(s)");
  } else {
    $("#grand_total").text(sum);
  }
}

$("#a,#b,#c").change(function() { calcSum($("#a,#b,#c")); });
```

Comment: Thanks, but the numbers need to multiplied together and I don't want the total shown unless there are 3 valid integers in the text inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Optimized version:

```
var a = parseInt($('#a').val(), 10) || 0,
    b = parseInt($('#b').val(), 10) || 0,
    c = parseInt($('#c').val(), 10) || 0;
    $('#grand_total').html(a+b+c);
```

Just make sure you use `10` as argument in `parseInt()` to avoid unpleasant surprises ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var $inputs = $("#a, #b, #c");
var $result = $("#grand_total");

$inputs.change(function() {    
    var sum = 0;
    var valid = true;

    $inputs.each(function() {
        var n = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);

        if ( isNaN(n) || n < 0 || n > 1000 ) { 
            return valid = false;
        } else {
            sum *= n;
        }
    });

    valid ? $result.text(sum).show() : $result.hide();
});
```